# Using dynamic text to display layer credits

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, cartography, dynamic-text

I'm looking for a way to update the 'layer credits' into a dynamic text box. I've found ways of using the map credits or data frame credits [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/working-with-dynamic-text.htm) but can't seem a way to get the information derived from a layer.

I just seem to produce an empty string every time. Has anyone done this or found a work around? Seems like an extremely useful way to update map credits with little to no resources.

[image: Derived Layer properties]

Comment: There is no way to do this dynamically, as the built-in dynamic texts are all based on the document or data frame. However, this is definitely possible if you're willing to run a script to populate a text field every time you make a map.  Or, even populate the map credits from all of the layer credits.  If this is what you're after, I can provide some  arcpy code to do so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, there isn't a way to do this using dynamic text.  However, you could write a script to do this and attach it to a python addin button or to run when you save the MXD or something.  You'll need to create a text element to hold the credits and name it something like "CREDITS" as so:

[image]

The basic code would look something like this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
credit_text = ""
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    credit_text += (layer.credits + "\n") # separate each line with a carriage return
for el in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if el.name == "CREDITS":
        el.text = credit_text
```

Comment: +1 That's how I'd do it - would have answered with much the same code.